# Mixed content the page at was loaded over https but requested an insecure script

Tags: ssl

My hosting provider has just implemented a SSL certificate on my website and I now see "Mixed content the page at mydomain.co.uk was loaded over https but requested an insecure script".

I understand from previous threads that I need to amend my htaccess file and have tried several options which have not been successful.  This is the current code in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?Filename=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost:8888
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/css text/javascript 
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge”
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Problem now fixed.  Found another thread with the answer.

Comment: A link to the answer and quote here would have been nice... :)